# Custom sort by direction and column name in Ecto

Tags: sql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In the first line I'm setting the `order_by` clause by hard coding the direction and column name.

```
order_by = [desc: :inserted_at]
results =
  from t in Transmission,
  where: ilike(t.name, ^"%#{params["term"]}%"),
  order_by: ^order_by
```

How can I set these dynamically? The UX is a user clicking on a table column header and changing the sort order of that particular field.

Couldn't find anything in the documentation: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#order_by/3

Imagine I have these two variables from the params object in my controller:

```
sort = "asc"
field_name = "inserted_at"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sort = "asc"
field_name = "inserted_at"

order_by = [{String.to_atom(sort), String.to_atom(field_name)}]
```

or

```
order_by = [{:"#{sort}", :"#{field_name}"}]
```

or even

```
[[sort, field_name]
 |> Enum.map(&String.to_atom/1)
 |> List.to_tuple]
#⇒ [asc: :inserted_at]
```

Under the hood, the keyword is a list of tuples, each having two elements.

```
iex(1)> [a: 42] == [{:a, 42}]
true
```

Comment: You should note, however, that creating atoms based on user input is generally considered bad practice since atoms are never removed/garbage collected. It's probably better to use `Atom.to_existing_atom` when expecting the input to be `:asc`/`:desc` or an existing field.